# c# Timer callback object context?

Tags: c#

I have a question using C# with its `Timers.Timer` class.  Given the below general outline:

1 - Is the callback running in the context of the object itself so I can just use the member variables (unlike C++ where you'd have to pass the object pointer)?

```
class A {
  Timer m_Timer;
  int m_JustForShow;

  public void TimerHandler(Object stateinfo) {
    // is this right?
    string id=(string) stateinfo;
    // use id to check if action has completed and if not
    // we cancel it.
    if (m_JustForShow==1) {
      // Is this running under the objects context and I can just do this?
    }
  }

  public void MyEventNotification(in MyEventInfo ei)
  {
    if (ei.State!=MyEventState.Completed) {
      m_Timer=new Timer(TimerHandler, new ei.StringID, 1000, Timeout.Infinite);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, a general capability of delegates.  They don't just store the method pointer but also the object of the class that the method belongs to.  It is inferred by the C# compiler, it simply uses this.TimerHandler to capture *this*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, timers run in the Thread Pool, not on the object. Because of this, it's usually best practice to utilize LOCKS to ensure that something else is not modifying your object at the same time your callback method is fired.

```
readonly object m_Lock = new object();

  public void TimerHandler(Object stateinfo) {
    string id = (string)stateinfo;

    // Use lock to ensure thread safety when accessing shared resources
    lock (m_Lock) {
      if (m_JustForShow == 1) {
        // Perform actions using m_JustForShow
      }
    }
  }
```

This also will prevent two callback threads executing the same code. If your code is very computation heavy and the timer is extremely fast, you could have multiple callbacks before the first one is finished. If this is a possibility, you can enhance the lock so threads will timeout to avoid excessive waiting/queueing. Using too many locks might lead to performance issues.